# Why jQuery does not raise error event when an ajax call fails

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why jQuery does not raise any `error` event when I execute following script?

thought I have registered the error event, but it is not fired.

chrome shows me following error in `Network` tab in `Console`.

`GET http://www.google.com/adfdaf?callback=jQuery15204572567550931126_1321347602706&_=1321348668347 404 (Not Found)`

**javascript:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://google.com/adfdaf?callback=?',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log('Custom Domain validated successfully.');
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error occured while validating Custom Domain.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is there any luck with using alert() instead of console.log()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery docs for [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) state the following:

> **error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)**
>
> A function to be called if the
>   request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in
>   jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of
>   error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs,
>   errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as
>   "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error
>   setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called
>   in turn. ***Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   JSONP requests.***

You can use [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead. For example:

```
$.getJSON("url?callback=?", function() {
    //Success!
}).error(function() {
    //Error!
});
```

**Edit**

Looks like that won't work either. It seems the workaround is to supply a `timeout` option to `.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://google.com/adfdaf?callback=?',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log('Custom Domain validated successfully.');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('Error occured while validating Custom Domain.');
    }
});
```

Obviously, that's not ideal, but the error handler will run after 5 seconds.

Comment: @ZainShaikh - Actually, don't use `.getJSON`! See my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documenation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

**Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests**

I could be screwing up my terminology but I assume by requesting from google that makes this a cross-domain request.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of JSONP - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-with-datatype-jsonp-will-not-use-error-callback-if-request-fails